# Merge an array of hashes by key-value pair

Tags: ruby, hash, key-value

I have an array of hashes as follows:

```
[
  {'abc_id'=>'1234', 'def_id'=>[]},
  {'abc_id'=>'5678', 'def_id'=>['11', '22']},
  {'abc_id'=>'1234', 'def_id'=>['33', '44']},
  {'abc_id'=>'5678', 'def_id'=>['55', '66']}
]
```

I'm trying to combine multiple hashes with the same key-value pair into one hash. Thus, we have two pairs with the same value for `'abc_id'` key as follows:

- `{'abc_id'=>'1234', 'def_id'=>[]}` and `{'abc_id'=>'1234', 'def_id'=>['33', '44']}`
- `{'abc_id'=>'5678', 'def_id'=>['11', '22']}` and `{'abc_id'=>'5678', 'def_id'=>['55', '66']}`

I'm expecting multiple hashes with the same key-value pairs to be merged into one individual hash. For the two pairs above, they should be respectively:

- `{'abc_id'=>'1234', 'def_id'=>['33', '44']}`
- `{'abc_id'=>'5678', 'def_id'=>['11', '22', '55', '66']}`

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to include the code you have written to try and solve this problem *as code* (not screenshot) *within the answer* (not on an external site), and describe *precisely* what the problem is with that code, and why it doesn't solve your problem. Include the full error message, if you get any (again, as text and within the question), as well as any results you are getting.

Comment: Further to @Jörg's comment, readers often want to cut-and-paste the asker's code, which cannot be done if it is presented in a picture, and links to external sites may in future be broken, so questions should not be reliant on the content of those links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more-or-less generic and extendable variant would be:

```
input.
  group_by { |h| h['abc_id'] }.
  map do |k, v|
    v.reduce do |acc, arr|
      #  use `+` instead of `|` to save duplicates  ⇓⇓⇓
      acc.merge(arr) { |_, v1, v2| Array === v1 ? v1 | v2 : v1 }
    end
  end
#⇒ [{"abc_id"=>"1234", "def_id"=>["33", "44"]},
#   {"abc_id"=>"5678", "def_id"=>["11", "22", "55", "66"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option more:

```
array
  .map.with_object({}) { |h, hh| hh[h['abc_id']].nil? ? hh[h['abc_id']] = h['def_id'] : hh[h['abc_id']] += h['def_id'] }
  .map{ |k, v| {'abc_id' => k, 'def_id' => v} }
```

The first part returns

```
# {"1234"=>["33", "44"], "5678"=>["11", "22", "55", "66"]}
```

The second part rebuilds the original structure, returning:

```
#=> [{"abc_id"=>"1234", "def_id"=>["33", "44"]}, {"abc_id"=>"5678", "def_id"=>["11", "22", "55", "66"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One could use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Here this needs to be done at two levels.

Letting `arr` be the array given in the question, these methods are used as follows.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g['abc_id']=>g) do |_,o,n|
    o.merge(n) { |k,oo,nn| k=='def_id' ? oo+nn : oo }
  end
end.values
  #=> [{"abc_id"=>"1234", "def_id"=>["33", "44"]},
  #    {"abc_id"=>"5678", "def_id"=>["11", "22", "55", "66"]}]
```

See the docs for an explanation of the block variables `_`, `o`, `n`, `k`, `oo` and `nn`. I used an underscore to represent the common key 
 with `update` to tell the reader that it is not used in the block calculation.

Note that the receiver of [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) is the following.

```
{ "1234"=>{ "abc_id"=>"1234", "def_id"=>["33", "44"] },
  "5678"=>{ "abc_id"=>"5678", "def_id"=>["11", "22", "55", "66"] } }
```